# Jmeter: Extract JSON block from response using particular JSON value

Tags: json, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing, jmeter-5.0

I'm trying to extract the JSON block from the HTTP response and depending on the condition, I want to extract a particular block of JSON. 
For eg.:

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

From the above JSON response, I want a block of a particular book where, price is less than 10 i.e.

```
{
     "category": "reference",
     "author": "Nigel Rees",
     "title": "Sayings of the Century",
     "price": 8.95
}
```

I'm trying to use JSON Extractor in JMeter 5.0.

Please help.

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this example:

```
$.store.book[?(@.price < 10)]
```

from the [JSONPath documenation](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-examples)?

It appears to be exactly what you're looking for:

[image]

---

Also be informed that according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so I would recommend upgrading to [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) (or [latest stable JMeter version](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)) as soon as possible